# Ember js multi text box form

Tags: ember.js

I have started to look at ember js but I am having problems getting my head around the view - template part, if I want one text box to fire a create event this is simple enough I use the insertNewline function on the Ember.TextField view, however most web application require a form to be filled out and submitted when a button is pressed, I can't seen to get the a view working that has multiple text input boxes on it.

I have followed the example on git hub https://github.com/mikecrittenden/tangletube however he seems to be referencing DOM elements directly from the view rather than Binding to properties of the view.

Does anyone have an example of an ember project that uses multi text field forms.

On a side note: There seems to be no standard structure to developing ember applications, every example I have looked at does things completely differently.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple example showing two ways of using multiple text fields in a view: http://jsfiddle.net/tomwhatmore/HEaGm/

The first one binds the textfields to their view using `viewName`, which lets the view access each of them using `this.get('whateverYouPutAsViewName')`.

The second binds the values of the textfields directly to an Ember object, by using `valueBinding`. Any changes you make to the fields will automatically update the object.

Both have a button which triggers a simple action which use the values to show how they are accessed in the view. Hopefully the code is pretty self-explanatory.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.HelloView}}
        {{view Ember.TextField viewName="firstName" placeholder="first name"}}
        {{view Ember.TextField viewName="lastName" placeholder="last name"}}
        <button {{action "hello"}}>Say Hello</button>
    {{/view}}

    {{#view App.BoundView}}
        {{#with person}}
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="firstName"}}
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="lastName"}}
        {{/with}}
        <button {{action "hello"}}>Say Hello</button>
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create()

App.HelloView = Ember.View.extend({
    hello: function() {
        alert("Hello " + this.get('firstName').get('value') + " " + this.get('lastName').get('value'));
    }
});

App.Person = Ember.Object.create({
    'firstName': 'John',
    'lastName': 'Doe',

    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

App.BoundView = Ember.View.extend({
    personBinding: 'App.Person',

    hello: function() {
        alert("hello " + this.get('person').get('fullName'));
    } 
})
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for, it now makes sense.  If I put a controller in between view and model is it just a case of calling the controler from the view action is this the correct way to do it or can it be done with bindings also.

Comment: @user655261 you can bind a controller to a view in exactly the same way e.g. `peopleBinding: "App.peopleController"`. Then in the view you would normally iterate over that controller using an `{{#each}}` block. e.g. `{{#each people}} {{fullName}} {{/each}}`

Answer (score 0):

The simple bindings example app on the emberjs site (http://emberjs.com/examples/) has multiple text boxes.

You may also want to checkout the sproutcore 2 (ember's previous name) demo app contest. http://blog.sproutcore.com/announcing-the-winners-of-the-demo-apps-contest/.

Generally speaking, to convert sproutcore 2 to emberjs, just change the SC namespace to Ember.